# SQL Server - Constraint to prevent two columns having specific values at the same time

Tags: sql-server

I have a table PO_HEADER -

```
PO_NO | STATUS | AUTHORISATION DATE | AUTHORISATION CODE | ....
```

In my application a PO is created with a status of 8 and then after authorisation the status is changed to 1.  My problem is that sometimes when the PO is being saved it is getting the status 1 instead of 8 despite there not being any code (that I can find) that does that.

So, is it possible to create a constraint that would prevent an update that tries to set "STATUS" to 1 while leaving "AUTHORISATION CODE" blank(null)?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT CK_your_Constraint_name  CHECK (STATUS = 1 AND (AUTHORISATION CODE = '' OR AUTHORISATION CODE IS NULL) )` But maybe you want to check for triggers on that table or transaction issues,its not good to control design flaws with check constraints

Comment: Ok i think I made a mistake,change `CHECK (STATUS != 1 AND.... ` since you DONT want that

Comment: There don't appear any triggers in the database at all and no transactions in the stored procedures involved.  I'm hoping the constraint will force an error and allow me to find what is setting the invalid status.

Comment: Thanks @Mihai I've basically gone with your first suggestion surrounded with a `NOT()` statement.  Can you post an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this check constraint

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT CK_your_Constraint_name 
CHECK (STATUS != 1 AND (AUTHORISATION CODE = '' OR AUTHORISATION CODE IS NULL) )
```